# How to calculate sphere rotation based off of UV coordinates

Tags: c++, math, rotation, geometry, unreal-engine4

I have a texture that I am wrapping around a sphere similar to this image on Wikipedia.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/UVMapping.png

What I am trying to achieve is to take a UV coordinate from the texture let's say (0.8,0.8) which would roughly be around Russia in the above example.

With this UV somehow calculate the rotation I would need to apply to the sphere to have that UV centred on the sphere.

Could someone point me in the right direction of the math equation I would need to calculate this?

Edit - it was pointed out that I am actually looking for the rotation of the sphere so the uv is centered towards the camera. So starting with the rotation of 0,0,0 my camera is pointed at the uv (0,0.5)

Thanks

Comment: "To have that UV centered on the sphere" -- you mean to have the *camera* looking at that UV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular type of spherical mapping has the very convenient property that the UV coordinates are *linearly* proportional to the corresponding *polar* coordinates.

Let's assume for convenience that:

- UV `(0.5, 0.5)` corresponds to the Greenwich Meridian line / Equator - i.e. `(0° N, 0° E)`
- The mesh is initially axis-aligned
- The texture is centered at spherical coordinates `(θ, φ) = (π/2, 0)` - i.e. the X-axis

A diagram to demonstrate:

[image]

Using the boundary conditions:

- `U = 0 -> φ = -π`
- `U = 1 -> φ = +π`
- `V = 1 -> θ = 0`
- `V = 0 -> θ = π`

We can deduce the required equations, and the corresponding direction vector `r` in the sphere's *local* space:

[image]

Assuming the sphere has rotation matrix `R` and is centered at `c`, simply use `lookAt` with:

- Position `c + d * (R * r)`
- Direction `-(R * r)`

Comment: Hi thanks for that, could you help me out with my example, I am trying to translate this to Unreal Engine 4 but feel i'm not quite understanding the math ?

I am using a left handed coordinate system.

UV - (0.49,0.21)

Sphere starting Position (0,0,0), Rotation (0,0,0)
Camera starting Position (0,-310,0), Rotation (0,0,90)

θ = (π(1 - 0.49)) -> 0.51π
φ = (π(2*0.21 - 1)) -> -0.58π

r = (
  sin(0.51π) * cos(-0.58π),
  sin(0.51π) * sin(-0.58π),
  cos(0.51π)
 )
r = (-0.249,-0.968,-0.031) which is the direction vector in sphere's local space

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your position and direction equations.
In unreal engine I can't get the rotation matrix but I can get a rotator which gives me yaw,pitch,roll values as well as things like the direction vector but I am not sure why I need these equations or how to substitute out the Rotation matrix.

Comment: Unreal has a Find Look At Rotation function which takes a start and target vector and returns the rotation. I thought I could take r calculated above, and multiply by my spheres radius to give it a world position as my sphere is at (0,0,0) and then use the cameras position and plug both of these into the look at function but it doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: You need to rotate the local space `r` vector by the sphere's rotation to get the corresponding direction in *world* space, where the camera resides. I'm unfamiliar with Unreal's specifics so cannot help much with the implementation detail side of things. Mind uploading some screen shots of "unexpected results"?

Comment: I think I'm missing something here as using the 90 degree intervals:

UV (0,0.5) = Direction -Z
UV(0.25,0.5) = Direction (0.707, 0, -0.707)
UV (0.5,0.5) = Direction +X
UV (0.75,0.5) = Direction (0.707, 0, 0.707)
UV (1,0.5) = Direction +Z

If I double the U coordinate I get the expected direction ?

My other issue is this only works if I leave the V coordinate on 0.5, e.g

UV(0.5,0.25) = Direction -Y ?

Comment: Please refrain from your habit of throwing random numbers at me, as I don't know enough about the peculiarities of your setup to know what they imply (not to mention that I can't read them due to your formatting either). However I did realize that I got the formula slightly wrong - my answer has been updated with the fixed one.

Comment: My apologies, I was trying to explain the unexpected results I was getting with basic UV coordinates. As i'd expect with each 0.25 increment the direction to be rotated by 90 degrees which wasn't the case.

It turns out it was just the formula that was messing me up. Thank you for all your help, I really appreciate it.